# how to find pixel coordinates of a specific point in an image in python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

I am going to find RGB values for each of 8 color patches on the left hand in this image.But how can I find the pixel coordinates for that specific point?
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEFfy.jpg)

I have tried the code below so I have RGB values of all pixels in an array.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("white_balance_example_color_checkers.jpg")
width , height = img.size
imgdata=np.array(img.getdata())
```

But how can I find that specific point?
As I know the size of image, which is 1000*667, I assume that the RGB values for pixel (x,y) will be in the row number (y*1000 + x ) !!

Is that really the best way? Or how can I do that more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just index the array with two dimensional indices: `imgdata[y, x]`. BTW, what you are asking about is the "linear index" of a 2D array. You can calculate a linear index manually like you state, but you can also use [`np.ravel_multi_index()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html).